# ActiveRecord query is forcing ORDER BY after DISTINCT

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, postgresql, activerecord, rails-activerecord

I am using this query:

```
Post.where("created_at >= ? AND created_at <= ?", 1.month.ago.beginning_of_month , 1.month.ago.end_of_month)
    .select('DISTINCT user_id')
```

Which returns 40 elements. However, I expect to get an array from this query, and to be able to iterate over this array with a `.each`. The issue is that when I try to use `.each` on the result of the query, I get this:

> ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: PG::InvalidColumnReference: ERROR:  for SELECT DISTINCT, ORDER BY expressions must appear in select list
>       LINE 1: ...ted_at <= '2016-06-30 21:59:59.999999')  ORDER BY created_at...
>                                                                    ^
>       : SELECT DISTINCT user_id FROM "posts" WHERE (created_at >= '2016-05-31 22:00:00.000000' AND created_at <= '2016-06-30 21:59:59.999999')  ORDER BY created_at DESC

It seems like this query forces a `ORDER BY` on the `created_at`, and makes it break since order_by isn't in the query.

To avoid this issue, I'm using:

```
Post.where("created_at >= ? AND created_at <= ?", 1.month.ago.beginning_of_month , 1.month.ago.end_of_month)
    .map{|p| p.user_id}.uniq
```

Which is less efficient.

Any idea why I'm getting this error?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try the following:

```
Post.where(created_at: (1.month.ago.beginning_of_month)..1.month.ago.end_of_month)
    .distinct.reorder(nil).pluck(:user_id)
```

As mentioned in the comments, this is due to a `default_scope`:

```
default_scope {order('created_at DESC')}
```

Comment: Same error: SELECT DISTINCT "posts"."user_id" FROM "posts" WHERE (created_at >= '2016-05-31 22:00:00.000000' AND created_at <= '2016-06-30 21:59:59.999999')  ORDER BY created_at DESC
ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: PG::InvalidColumnReference: ERROR:  for SELECT DISTINCT, ORDER BY expressions must appear in select list
LINE 1: ...ted_at <= '2016-06-30 21:59:59.999999')  ORDER BY created_at...
                                                             ^

Comment: Still an error:

ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: PG::InvalidColumnReference: ERROR:  for SELECT DISTINCT, ORDER BY expressions must appear in select list
LINE 1: ...ted_at <= '2016-06-30 21:59:59.999999')  ORDER BY created_at...
                                                             ^
: SELECT DISTINCT "posts"."user_id" FROM "posts" WHERE (created_at >= '2016-05-31 22:00:00.000000' AND created_at <= '2016-06-30 21:59:59.999999')  ORDER BY created_at DESC

Comment: It works if I change .pluck(:user_id) to .pluck(:user_id, :created_at), but that's not the result I want bc I'll need to iterate over the result to extract only the user_id

Comment: What's forced order ?

Comment: @GrahamSlick: By the way, do you have a default scope or something like this, so `order by` clause is added to query?

Comment: Ok amazing so your answer works, and your assumption about the default_scope was indeed the issue. Thanks a lot, you helped a lot !